# react-navigation - navigating back to previous screen after opening app from deep link not working

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, react-navigation

I'm trying to implement deep linking in a React Native app but I'm having trouble maintaining the expected back-button behavior when closing out of a view nested in a stack navigator. My root navigator is a StackNavigator which has a TabNavigator with path 'customer'. Inside the tab navigator there are four tabs, one of which has path 'order-now' with the screen being another StackNavigator.  That OrderNow stack has 3 child screens that look like this:

```
const OrderNowTab = StackNavigator({
  Root: { screen: StoresScreen, path: 'show-stores' },
  Menu: { screen: StoreItemsScreen, path: 'show-stores/:store_id'},
  Item: { screen: ItemDetailsScreen, path: 'show-stores/:store_id/:item_id'}
});
```

When I follow the [Deep Linking guides](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/linking) by running `adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "mychat://mychat/customer/order-now/show-stores/some_store_id/some_item_id" com.sampleapp` I DO get taken to the item details screen as expected, but when I press the back arrow button within the navigation header, the app appears to close the screen and land on another which is an exact copy of the one just closed (item details). The only difference is this new screen doesn't have a back arrow button within the header, giving me the impression that it's at the root of this stack navigator when it shouldn't be (pressing back should have brought me to `StoreItemsScreen`).

Why does this happen and how can I get the `StoreItemsScreen` to show after pressing the back button (either from the navigation header or physical Android back button) instead?

My `package.json` file's dependencies section looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.48.1",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
  },
```

And here are the file's I'm using:

```
// src/App.js
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const SampleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: require('./HomeScreen') },
  CustomerTabBar: { screen: require('./customer/CustomerNavigator'), path: 'customer' },
  Chat: { screen: require('./customer/ChatScreen'), path: 'chat/:user' },
}, {mode: "modal", headerMode: "none"});

const prefix = Platform.OS == 'android' ? 'mychat://mychat/' : 'mychat://'

const MainApp = () => <SampleApp uriPrefix={prefix} />

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => MainApp);
```

`src/HomeScreen.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Text, Button, View} from 'react-native'

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello, Chat App!</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigate('Chat', { user: 'Lucy' })}
          title="Chat with Lucy"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = HomeScreen
```

`CustomerNavigator.js`:

```
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const CustomerNavigator = TabNavigator({
  OrderNow: { screen: require('./OrderNowTab'), path: 'order-now' },
  FutureOrders: { screen: require('./FutureOrdersScreen'), path: 'future-order' },
  Bag: { screen: require('./BagScreen'), path: 'bag-tab' },
  YourOrders: { screen: require('./YourOrdersScreen'), path: 'your-orders' },
  Account: { screen: require('./AccountScreen'), path: 'your-account' },
},{
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#000',
  }
})

module.exports = CustomerNavigator
```

`OrderNowTab.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class StoresScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `Stores`,
  });
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>List of Stores</Text>
    )
  }
}

class StoreItemsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `Store Items`,
  });
  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    return (
      <Text>Store Items Screen for store with id {params.store_id}</Text>
    )
  }
}

class ItemDetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: 'Item Details'
  })
  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state
    return (
      <Text>Item details screen for item with id {params.item_id} and store with id {params.store_id}</Text>
    )
  }
}

const OrderNowTab = StackNavigator({
  Root: { screen: StoresScreen, path: 'show-stores' },
  Menu: { screen: StoreItemsScreen, path: 'show-stores/:store_id'},
  Item: { screen: ItemDetailsScreen, path: 'show-stores/:store_id/:item_id'}
});

module.exports = OrderNowTab
```

And here is a gif of what it currently looks like:
[image]